# Ownership of buttons via an IBOutletCollection

Tags: cocoa-touch, view, controller, reference-counting, iboutletcollection

Please confirm this if I understand it correctly about outlet collections.

Let's say I have four buttons in a View, in a storyboard file, and 
I used an outlet collection to link those buttons to my controller.

Now, I have three things to confirm:

1. The view has four strong pointers to the buttons inside an array, but the view does not know about the array -- it does not have a pointer to the array, correct?
2. The controller has a strong pointer to the array and that makes the array's members to be strongly pointed at again (one reference count from the view and one reference count from the Controller), correct?
3. So, when it is released from one side (either the view or the controller), it won't be deallocated in the program, correct?